# Pass UITextField (password) from VC1 and comparing (is/is not the same) with UITextField (confirm password) on VC2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

`ViewController2` "*Enter Password*" `UITextField` value needs to be passed to `ViewController3`.

The `ViewController3` "*Confirm Password*" `UITextField` value needs to be compared with the `ViewController2` "*Enter Password*" `UITextField` when the user clicks the "*Next*" `UIButton`.

If the values are different, a "*Passwords do not match*" `UILabel` needs to be made visible above the `UITextField`, and the "*Next*" `UIButton` needs to go back to being inactive.

At the moment, both `UITextFields` have criteria in that a minimum of 6 characters is required, so the "*Next*" `UIButton` remains inactive until criteria is satisfied.

**ViewController2.swift**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var toViewController3Button: UIButton!

@IBAction func backToViewController1(_ sender: Any) {
    print("back button pressed")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController2ToViewController1Segue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func toViewController3(_ sender: Any) {
    print("next button pressed")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController2ToViewController3Segue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func textFieldChangedValue(_ sender: UITextField) {
    toViewController3Button.isEnabled = sender.text!.count >= 6
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("ViewController2 has loaded")
    // Is off until password criteria is satisfied
    toViewController3Button.isEnabled = false
    // Set delegate
    passwordField.delegate = self
    passwordField.becomeFirstResponder()
    passwordField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChangedValue(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}

// Hide keyboard when Return key is pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("Keyboard Hidden by Return Key")
    return true
}

// Global: Hide Keyboard when screen is touched outside of text field
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    print("Keyboard Hidden by Screen Tap")
}

// Confirm Password field must have 6 or more characters for Next -> button to activate
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == passwordField {
        let countAfter = textField.text!.count + string.count - range.length
        toViewController3Button.isEnabled = countAfter >= 6
    }
    return true
}
}
```

**ViewController3.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController3: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var toViewController4Button: UIButton!

@IBAction func backToViewController2(_ sender: Any) {
    print("back button pressed")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController3ToViewController2Segue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func toViewController4(_ sender: Any) {
    print("next button pressed")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController3ToViewController4Segue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func textFieldChangedValue(_ sender: UITextField) {
    toViewController4Button.isEnabled = sender.text!.count >= 6
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("ViewController3 has loaded")
    // Is off until password criteria is satisfied
    toViewController4Button.isEnabled = false
    // Set delegate
    confirmPasswordField.delegate = self
    confirmPasswordField.becomeFirstResponder()
    confirmPasswordField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChangedValue(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}

// Hide keyboard when Return key is pressed
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    confirmPasswordField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("Keyboard Hidden by Return Key")
    return true
}

// Global: Hide Keyboard when screen is touched outside of text field
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    print("Keyboard Hidden by Screen Tap")
}

// Confirm Password field must have 6 or more characters for Next -> button to activate
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if textField == confirmPasswordField {
        let countAfter = textField.text!.count + string.count - range.length
        toViewController4Button.isEnabled = countAfter >= 6
    }
    return true
}
}
```

Alternatively, if the values from both `UITextFields` can be compared on-the-fly in real time as the user is entering characters into the "*Confirm Password*" `UITextField`, then that is fine too (instead of using the "*Next*" `UIButton` to initiate the comparison).

I am too inexperienced to know which route is the best, so any other advise is of course welcome.

I was able to pass the data from VC1 to VC2 (as seen in below code snippets), but was unable to figure out how to hook the rest of it together.

**ViewController1.swift:**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

var passwordText = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func done(_ sender: Any) {
    self.passwordText = passwordField.text!
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController1ToViewController2", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var vc = segue.destination as! ViewController2
    vc.passwordFieldValue = self.passwordText
}
}
```

**ViewController2.swift:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var passwordFieldValue: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordField: UITextField!

var passwordFieldValue = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    passwordFieldValue.text = passwordFieldValue
}

@IBAction func backToViewController(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Back to ViewController")
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ViewController2ToViewController1", sender: self)
}
}
```

Comment: Don't pass around the `UITextField`, pass the password itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass around the `UITextField`. Prepare a model instead. I'm guessing you are trying to implement a signup flow. So create a signup request model as follows.

```
struct SignupRequestModel {
    var email: String? // guessing you are using email 
    var password: String?
    var confirmedPassword: String?
    // ... other fields, which you require to complete signup
}
```

Then as you passing around the `UITextField`, instead of that, pass an instance of `SignupRequestModel`, gradually setting all it's properties.

Hope you get my point of view.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass `UITextField` to next `ViewController`. You can pass a `textField.text` its self.

> You are going to compare two strings. If its mismatch you can pop
>   back.

So, You can change our code like **ViewController2**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

     let conformViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController3
     conformViewController.password = passwordTextField.text ?? ""
    }
```

**In ViewController3**

```
var password: String = ""
```

Then you can compare in ViewController3

```
let confirmPassword = confirmPasswordField.text ?? ""


if password == confirmPassword {
nextButton.isEnabled = true
} else {
label.text=“password mismatched”
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your instruction... I applied it, but am getting some errors and build is failing.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ruuhl5u30hwm26e/stackoverflow-Pass%20UITextField%20%28password%29%20from%20VC1%20and%20comparing%20%28is%3Ais%20not%20the%20same%29%20with%20UITextField%20%28confirm%20password%29%20on%20VC2-1.png?dl=0

Comment: 1. 1. `In declaration of 'ViewController3'` and 2. `Cannot use instance member 'confirmPasswordField' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

Comment: Did you follow my instructions? It’s warming or error?

Comment: Yes I followed your instructions.  The build fails.

Comment: Where exactly does the ViewController3 code need to be within the document/code?  https://www.dropbox.com/s/jl0suswado4td2r/Screenshot%202018-12-28%2021.28.24.png?dl=0

Comment: I have updated my code. And Where your getting a error in this?